# Append To Select List If Option Isn't Already There

Tags: jquery

I want to append to a select list only if the selected option is not already there. Currently, I have this:

```
$('#columnsAvailable').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
```

Can someone help me insert a statement that checks if "$(this).val()" is already there or not, I don't want to insert duplicate values? Thanks!

Comment: Where does the selected option come from?? Are you adding the value from 1 dropdown to another?

Comment: @Ajo Koshy - Ye. This is two multiple select lists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like

```
var optionExists = ($('#columnsAvailable option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').length > 0);

if(!optionExists)
{
    $('#columnsAvailable').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Added a "+" for the string concatenation. Works perfectly now :)

Comment: Cool, sorry about the typo

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
//get all the elements in an array
var values = $('#columnsAvailable').children('option').map(function(i, e){
    return e.value || e.innerText;
}).get();

//check if new element exists in the array    
if( $.inArray($(this).val(), values) > -1 ) {
    $('#columnsAvailable').append(
        "<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>"
    );
}
```

Comment: I think the last bit would make it so it adds *if the option already exists*. `($.inArray(option, values) == -1 )` ?