# Search and write into drop down menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

How can in the same time search and write in a select drop down menu
in general the select drop down menu we can't write in side 
is there a method can i use it to write inside this drop down menu and during typing if it contain a similar word appear if not i can continue writing and save this info into database

```
<select name='Name'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Mark">Mark</option>
<option value="alin">alin</option>
</select>
```

in this example if i write mark mark appear and i choose it in i write sami i dont have this name i can write and submit my form and it will be in the database

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess that English isn't your first language, but this is unintelligible. Please try to spend a little more time on writing your question, and using punctuation to make it clear what you're asking. Try Google Translate maybe?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave what i try to explain is the select menu be two in one select menu and input field

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var country = ["Australia", "Denmark", "Hong Kong", "India", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "South Africa"];
                $("#country").select2({
                  data: country
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>DropDown with Search using jQuery</h1>
        <div>
            <select id="country" style="width:300px;">
            <!-- Dropdown List Option -->
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what i ask is the input field be two select and input if the word exist appear on the search if not i can add it

Comment: in that case, you may use the methods mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298088/append-to-select-list-if-option-isnt-already-there